# Scanner scanning speed in Ubuntu 18.04 orders of maginitude slower than Win7 in Virtualbox on same computer

Tags: usb, scanner

I have an HP G3110 scanner connected via USB to my Dell 3420 16GB machine running Ubuntu 18.04. Th scanner runs like a dog using gscan2pdf which, after trying other scanner programs, was light years faster than them. However, I also have VirtualBox on the same computer with a Win7 Pro client. I rarely bring up VB (mostly to do the scanning). Compared to gscan2pdf which seems to take minutes to even get started scanning, much less finishing, the Win7 using the original HP scan software can finish dozens of scans in the same time period.

Anyone have an idea why my Ubuntu would be much slower than the same hardware on the same system with a VB Win7?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why is a scanner slower on ubuntu than on the same system using Windows?